# Twitter RSS feed snapshot

Tags: twitter, rss

I'm writing an app that will offer RSS feeds for Twitter, but I can't seem to be able to find any sample of how the Twitter RSS feed looked before it has been retired. Does anyone have a snapshot laying around or can point me to where I can find something archived? Thanks.

PS. I'm not sure if SO is the right place to ask these types of questions, please feel free to move it wherever it belongs.

Comment: You want to read from twitter as RSS Feed or you want to publish yours RSS Feeds on Twitter?

Comment: I already made a service that queries the Twitter API and offers an RSS feed of the user's timeline. However I would like my RSS feed to be as close as possible to what Twitter were offering before retiring RSS feeds. That's why I was wondering if anyone has something saved.

Comment: In short... you want to replicate twitter but as an RSS Feed Producer/Publisher... right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of searching, I found some items :

- http://pc.mogeringo.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/twitterRSS2.jpg
- http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-0yehz26gMp8/UL4zmXCvmII/AAAAAAAADJE/l4tDU1pyiR0/s640/3.png
- http://office-watch.com/articlefiles/842-Excel%202007%20-%20Web%20Query%20with%20Twitter%20RSS.jpg

Which can tell you how to build your XML, something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:twitter="http://api.twitter.com" version="2.0" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <channel>
        <title>Twitter / {{ user}}</title>
        <link>http://twitter.com/{{ user }}</link>
        <language>en-us</language>
        <ttl>40</ttl>
        {{#feed}}
        <item>
            <title>{{ title }}</title>
            <description>{{title}}</description>
            <pubDate>{{date}}</pubDate>
            <guid>http://twitter.com/{{ user }}/statuses/{{ guid}}</guid>
            <link>http://twitter.com/{{ user }}/statuses/{{ guid}}</link>
            <!-- and optionnaly -->
            <twitter:source>{{ source }}</twitter:source>
            <twitter:place>{{ geolocation }}</twitter:place>
        </item>
        {{/feed}}
    </channel>
</rss>
```

I used a `Mustache` like template, which is clear enough I believe.

Hope it'll help!

Comment: It sure does! If there'll be no further answers, get ready for the booty! Uh, I mean bounty. :)

Comment: Thank you for the booty, uh, the bounty ! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Archive.org sometimes archives .rss feeds, and they have [good coverage](http://tinyurl.com/3bdqf8) of Twitter.

Here's an example from 2011 :

http://web.archive.org/web/20110313193657/http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/33998183.rss